# Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception when Kinect device is attached or removed

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, kinect

I am developing a window service application which detectes the kinect devices attached with system and renders the data. I am using Microsfot's SDK for kinect. As far as device is already attached before running the application it works fine. But as i remvoe the device from system or attach the device to the system when my application is running i got unhandlled exception of object reference not found. Stack trace of that application is as follow

```
--------------------System.NullReferenceException--------------------

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui.KinectDeviceCollection.CINuiInstanceHelper_OnStatusChanged(CStatusChangedEventArgs args)

   at INuiInstanceHelper.CINuiInstanceHelper.RaiseOnStatusChanged(_NuiStatusData* pStatusArgs)

   at ?A0xc93b94dd.NuiStatusCallback(_NuiStatusData* pStatusArgs)
```

I also registered the 'StatusChanged' event. If i do it in the desktop application i works fine it detects both the removal and attachment of device, but when i do in window service it gives the error. Code in both applications are same. Also i have noticed that when i register the 'StatusChanged' event in a separate thread (Other than main app thread) in desktop application then it start giving the same error. I also registered the AppDomain's 'UnhandledException' event to stop crashing my application but it didn't stopped crashing.

---

Follwing is the code. If you create the instance of KinectManager class and call its start method then the kinect device detection thread will be started. Now if you attach or remove the kinect device after running the application the KinectManager instance will successfully detects this event and will never crash. But if the 'StatusChanged' event registration in Start method is commented and register this event in the Kinect device detection thread then after running application when kinect device is attached or removed the unhandled exception occurred.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Research.Kinect.Nui;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Kinect_Manager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Kinect manager class
    /// </summary>
    public class KinectManager
    {
        #region DATA MEMBERS
        private readonly Object _StartSync = new Object();
        private Object _RunTimeSync = new Object();
        private AutoResetEvent stopWait;
        private Dictionary<String, Runtime> detectedRuntimes;
        private List<String> initilizedRunTimes;
        #endregion

        #region PROPERTIES
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets true if kinect manager is started, else false.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Started { get; private set; }
        #endregion

        #region CONSTRUCTOR
        /// <summary>
        /// Consructor
        /// </summary>
        public KinectManager()
        {
            this.stopWait = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            this.Started = false;
            this.detectedRuntimes = new Dictionary<String, Runtime>();
            this.initilizedRunTimes = new List<String>();

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
        }
        #endregion

        #region PRIVATE METHODS
        /// <summary>
        /// Thread to detect any Kinect device attached and initialzes it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="state">Thread state.</param>
        private void DetectKinectThread(Object state)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (this._StartSync)
                {
                    if (!this.Started) return;

                    //To raise the unhandled exception on kinect attach or detech after Start() method call uncomment following line.
                    //Runtime.Kinects.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs>(Kinects_StatusChanged);
                }

                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!this.Started) return;

                        foreach (Runtime runTime in Runtime.Kinects)
                        {
                            if (!this.Started) return;
                            if (this.detectedRuntimes.ContainsKey(runTime.InstanceName)) continue;

                            this.detectedRuntimes.Add(runTime.InstanceName, runTime);
                            this.InitilizeRunTime(runTime);
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (this.Started)
                        {
                            this.stopWait.Reset();
                            this.stopWait.WaitOne(5000);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                //Runtime.Kinects.StatusChanged -= new EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs>(Kinects_StatusChanged);
                { try { Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(); } catch { } }//Abort current thread and ingore any exception while doing it.
            }
        }

        private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) { }

        private void Kinects_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.InitilizeRunTime(e.KinectRuntime);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        private void KinectRuntime_VideoFrameReady(object sender, ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e) { }

        private void KinectRuntime_DepthFrameReady(object sender, ImageFrameReadyEventArgs e) { }

        private void KinectRuntime_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e) { }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initilizes the run time if status is connected.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="runTime">Runtime instance.</param>
        private void InitilizeRunTime(Runtime runTime)
        {
            try
            {
                Monitor.Enter(this._RunTimeSync);

                if (!this.detectedRuntimes.ContainsKey(runTime.InstanceName)) return;

                if (runTime.Status != KinectStatus.Connected)
                {
                    if (this.initilizedRunTimes.Contains(runTime.InstanceName))
                    {
                        runTime.Uninitialize();
                        this.initilizedRunTimes.Remove(runTime.InstanceName);
                    }

                    return;
                }
                else if (this.initilizedRunTimes.Contains(runTime.InstanceName)) return; //Because run time is already initilized

                RuntimeOptions runtimeOptions = RuntimeOptions.UseDepthAndPlayerIndex | RuntimeOptions.UseSkeletalTracking | RuntimeOptions.UseColor;

                runTime.Initialize(runtimeOptions);
                runTime.VideoStream.Open(ImageStreamType.Video, 2, ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, ImageType.Color);
                runTime.DepthStream.Open(ImageStreamType.Depth, 2, ImageResolution.Resolution320x240, ImageType.DepthAndPlayerIndex);

                if (runtimeOptions.HasFlag(RuntimeOptions.UseSkeletalTracking))
                {
                    runTime.SkeletonEngine.TransformSmooth = true;
                    runTime.SkeletonEngine.SmoothParameters = new TransformSmoothParameters
                    {
                        Smoothing = 1.0f,
                        Correction = 0.1f,
                        Prediction = 0.1f,
                        JitterRadius = 0.05f,
                        MaxDeviationRadius = 0.05f
                    };
                }

                runTime.VideoFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(KinectRuntime_VideoFrameReady);
                runTime.DepthFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(KinectRuntime_DepthFrameReady);
                runTime.SkeletonFrameReady += new EventHandler<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(KinectRuntime_SkeletonFrameReady);

                this.initilizedRunTimes.Add(runTime.InstanceName);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                { try { runTime.Uninitialize(); } catch { } } // ignore any exception

                if (this.initilizedRunTimes.Contains(runTime.InstanceName)) { this.initilizedRunTimes.Remove(runTime.InstanceName); }

                if (exp is COMException)
                {
                    COMException comException = exp as COMException;
                    if (comException.ErrorCode == -2147220947)  //Runtime is being used by another app.
                    {
                        //Log that this kinect device is used by  another app.
                        return;
                    }
                }

                //Log detail exception here.
            }
            finally { Monitor.Exit(this._RunTimeSync); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region PUBLIC METHODS
        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the kinect manager.
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            lock (this._StartSync)
            {
                if (this.Started) return;

                this.stopWait.Reset();

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.DetectKinectThread);
                this.Started = true;

                //To raise the unhandled exception on kinect attach or detech after Start() method call comment following event registration.
                //and uncomment the event registration in DetectKinectThread thread
                Runtime.Kinects.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs>(Kinects_StatusChanged);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the kinect manager.
        /// </summary>
        public void Stop()
        {
            lock (this._StartSync)
            {
                this.Started = false;
                this.stopWait.Set();

                Runtime.Kinects.StatusChanged -= new EventHandler<StatusChangedEventArgs>(Kinects_StatusChanged);

                Runtime[] allRunTimes = new Runtime[this.detectedRuntimes.Count];
                this.detectedRuntimes.Values.CopyTo(allRunTimes, 0);
                this.detectedRuntimes.Clear();
                this.initilizedRunTimes.Clear();

                foreach (Runtime runTime in allRunTimes) { try { runTime.Uninitialize(); } catch { } }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where the exception occurs.

Comment: This could be a bug. There is a MS Kinect forum you could ask this question. Maybe you can get in touch with a Kinect developer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdknuiapi/

Comment: @juergend Thank you. I have posted the question at MS Kinect forum. BTW did you checked my code are you getting the same exception ?

Comment: I did not run your code. I do not have access to a Kinect device at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran your code and I am getting the exact error that you are getting.  Obviously the Kinect SDK is pre-release software and at the moment there is nothing you can do other than putting the code in a try-catch block.

I was also looking in the native libraries and I think if all you want to do is detect on/off stages, you should either port your code to C++ or wait for the final binaries to come out. C++ gives you more flexibility.

Good luck!